# JQuery - Ajax - Scroll and setInterval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with scroll and setInterval.

Here is the code :

```
function displayChat(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat/fetch_chat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data:{
            fetch: 1,
        },
        success: function(response){
            $("#chat_area").html(response);
            $("#chat_area").scrollTop($("#chat_area")[0].scrollHeight);
        }
    })
};
setInterval(displayChat, 1000);
```

When new data was inserted, div area with **"chat_area"** id will automatically go scroll down. But when I am trying to scrolling it up, it's forcing **"chat_area"** to scroll down again. I know it's because **setInterval**.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: remove the scrolTop line

Comment: you want to scroll up or down?

Comment: @madalinivascu what I want, if new data coming, it will scrolling down automatically and I can scroll it up

Comment: `async: false` lock your browser during the request so you can't scroll manually maybe it's your problem.

Comment: @GameTag I have tried to remove async: false, but the problem still exist

Comment: So if I understand, you don't want a new execution of `displayChat` while the `success` callback is not finish right ?

Comment: What I want is when I am scrolling "chat_area" it doesn't forcing back to scroll down

Comment: Well, you explicitely instruct to scroll down every second. Your code is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. And `async:false` = YURGH

Comment: Don't scroll it if it isn't already at the top before adding content.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const chart = $("#chat_area");

setInterval(displayChat, 1000);

function displayChat() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat/fetch_chat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {
            fetch: 1,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            chart.html(response).trigger('ajaxUpdate');
        }
    })
};


$(() => {

    chart.one('ajaxUpdate', '', (event) => {
        event.target.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "center",
            inline: "start"
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: Possible I didn't test it..
Email me that error on  szunaj13pl@gmail.com
Cheers